# Process terminated with status -1073741819 In C

Tags: c, codeblocks

While I'm running this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

int i=0;
int *arrNum = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
if(arrNum == NULL)
              {
            puts("Failed to allocate memory !!!");
            exit(1);
              }
        while(i<5)
        {
        printf("Number %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d", arrNum[i]);
        i++;
        }
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
            if(arrNum[i]%3==0)
                printf("%d\n", arrNum[i]);
            }
free(arrNum);
return 0;
}
```

Im Getting the error : Process terminated with status -1073741819 ,
What the reason ,how should i correct my code that would work ? In C.Thanks bvery much

Comment: That's an access violation, a standard failure mode for C code.  Your scanf() function call is broken, use &arrNum[i].  Given the dreadful indenting and the apparent lack of access to a debugger, I'd say you ought to keep looking for a more helpful IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `scanf` you are not providing the address of individual elements of array

Fix :

```
 scanf("%d", &arrNum[i]);
             ^ use &
```

Answer (score 0):

scanf requires the second argument to be a address

replace the "scanf("%d", arrNum[i]);" with 
scanf("%d", &arrNum[i]);or scanf("%d", arrnum+i);